# How did static charge ruin my control board?

Tags: pcb, heat, repair, thermistor, diy

We have a Thermia geothermal heat pump that was working fine up until we had a particularly bad thunderstorm.  Lightning took out the power for a while and burned up a DSL modem, a router, and a IP Cam.

After the storm I noticed that the heat pump registered the outside temperature way too low.  This is a water based system with radiators in the house and no thermostat.  It works by knowing the outside temperature and you can adjust the curve of how much heating you need.  After diagnosing it and finding some documentation I found the values the thermistor should be registering.

[image]

It checked out correct and the wiring was not causing a problem.  When I shorted the two terminals it was reading 9° which from this chart is about 250Ω too much.  There are 3 other thermistors reading other values that are still working properly but they use a much higher resistance (1-70kohm).

[image]

The pins marked in red are other thermistors that have a much higher resistance. The blue ones are for a thermostat that I don't have but I would love to understand if anyone knows how it works.  All of the thermistors are connected to pin one which I suspect is ground.  The outside temperature is read on pin 6 marked with an arrow.

My big question is how can I get the values to start reading correct again?  What should I check or replace?  I have started by checking all of the resistors and they seem to be ok.  I would like to fix this so I don't have to spend $500 for a new board if they are even possible to buy.

Comment: The IC with the text CD4051BCM has a weird bulb on it at pin 9, so it might be damaged (IC is left of the IC with text PIC16C73A. Please note that questions on the repair of electronics are prone to be closed for being off-topic.

Comment: If you have a signal source and a 50~220 Ohm series R you can test each pin with a DSO and test it like a Huntron Tracker to look for shorted nodes on each IC.

Comment: @Huisman I checked it out last night and i was just some flux or glue stuck to the top.

Answer (score 1):

Measure the protection diodes - 3 pins marked with A7, first. The one measured with low resistance, needs to be desoldered to measure it correctly . If the resistance is still low, you have to replace the opamp LM324. If you're lucky, then it should work with removing the diodes.

You would need a hot air gun and some skills to desolder/solder components without damaging the board.

EDIT:

More likely it's the input capacitor that is damaged.

Comment: How can i check the diodes?  I swapped the one on that circuit out with another on an unused pin and it was not changed.  I assume I must desolder the capacitor to check it?  How do you know what the value should be if it isn't marked?